# WooCommerce REST API Basic Auth not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, basic-authentication, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a main site (Wordpress **without** Woocommerce), where I've setup a PHP file to access the WooCommerce REST API (**to get the products**) in different subdomain sites (Also Wordpress sites but the **subdomains have WooCommerce**).

These Subdomain sites have the Woocommerce REST API Checkbox Ticked, and I've setup a user for each with read permissions.

I've HTTPS setup in all the websites (domain and subdomains), so I've been trying to use the BASIC AUTH but I can't get it right, here's a Postman with an example

[image: postman with example]

- When I login in the subdomain I get the data... but shouldn't it log in automatically?
- Is it my server that's not allowing the Basic Auth to work?
- Should I need some plugin in the subdomain wordpress to get the Basic Auth working (I've already tried... but nothing)

Let me know your thoughts and here's some data so you guys can do some requests:

- **Request Example URL:** https://garrafeira.cityshopping.pt/wp-json/wc/v2/products
- **Consumer Key:** ck_76b95ddf9d00d0bf494f9d92e355c9b43cbdb497
- **Consumer Secret:** cs_8040c552b486e2caa4512e6fb0a3249fffefc589

Thanks in advance